# Is there any simplest way to create graphql server in next13 without using any toolkit (apollo, grafbase,graphql-yoga)

Tags: server, graphql, mern, next.js13

I am trying to make the graphql server in next 13 without using any toolkit like apollo, grafbase,graphql-yoga. Just pure graphql server. But i am getting the error in the browser:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()

Why I am unable to use this. Or can you please suggest the simplest way to create pure graphql server inside the next13.

HERE is my code:
api/graphql/route.js:

```
import schema from "../schema";
import resolvers from "../resolvers";
import {graphql} from "graphql";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
export async function POST() {
  // const { query } = req.body;
console.log("Helo")
  const response = await graphql(schema, query, resolvers);
  console.log(response);

  return NextResponse.json(JSON.stringify(response));
}
```

Trying to fetch like this:
app/login/page.js:

```
'use client';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function GraphQLAPI() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRequest = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('/api/graphql', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ query: '{ hello }' }),
      });

      const { data } = await response.json;
      console.log(data);
    };

    handleRequest();
  }, []);

  return <div>GraphQL API</div>;
}
```

Dependencies are:

```
"autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "bson": "^5.3.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint": "8.40.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.2",
    "graphql": "^15.8.0",
    "micro": "^10.0.1",
    "mongodb": "^5.5.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.2.1",
    "next": "13.4.2",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^8.1.0",
    "postcss": "8.4.23",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2"
```

Please suggest me the simplest way to create graphql server without using any toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

While I'd always recommend using a framework or library for this kind of thing (because most likely a lot more edge cases and security issues have been caught already) it is possible to do something like the following using `graphql`:

```js
import { GraphQLError, graphql } from "graphql";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

function handler(req: NextRequest) {
  const { method, body } = req;

  if (method !== "GET" && method !== "POST") {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Method not allowed" },
      {
        status: 405,
        headers: {
          Allow: "GET,POST",
        },
      }
    );
  }

  const { query, variables, operationName } = body;

  try {
    const result = await graphql({
      schema,
      variableValues: variables,
      operationName,
      source: query,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return NextResponse.json(new GraphQLError(err.message));
  }
}

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Note: You'll need to pass it your `schema` and handle the `GET` request. You could get from the `url` the query params and check for `query` and if that is not present, return another error similar to the method not allowed.